# How to get data from firebase which is inside a unique ID

Tags: android, listview, firebase-realtime-database, adapter

LoadUserInfo Method

```
public void loadUserInformation() {

    final String uid = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
    ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
//                    String name=postSnapshot.child("Name").getValue().toString();;
//                    Name.setText(name);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error Loading Messages",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };
    rootRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
}
```

I know how to fetch  a static data like a data which is defined by me. But i want to retrive messages and display in listview. the problem is i use push method and every message creates a unique id and inside it contains message. how to i ignore the unique id and just fetch the message and display in listview? can some provide the code for adapter cuz im still a beginner...
Datatbase - http://ibb.co/fcRrxG

Comment: Seen this? https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md

Comment: What was wrong with `postSnapshot.child("Name").getValue()`? Try adding it to some adapter, not set one TextView... Where is your adapter / listview defined here?

Comment: I havnt yet defined. im not yet sure on how to do that... but fetching the data to a textview using this method works fine

Comment: can i get the code to fetch it in listview please?

Comment: Because the messages are inside the unique id. i dont knw how to access that

Comment: You shouldn't need to worry about the ID... You're never extracting the datasnapshot id. Just get the name, add it to an arraylist. Please try something on your own, [edit] your question to include what issues you face doing so

Comment: Have you solved the issue?

Comment: Not yet.........

Answer (score 0):

Try to make one single node of chat between two users in messages node in your database.
Let say, make a node with your id and with your friend id and in that node add chat messages in HashMap.
And, when retrieving it get that HashMap of your node.

Comment: I dont knw how to do that... can i get the code of that plz?